# Find out which ciphers are supported by a server using Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, server-side, metasploit

I'm trying to write/modify a metasploit module to find out which ciphers are supported by a server (for scanning purposes). Will I have to enumerate the ciphers, by trying them all out, or is there a way I can request from the server which ciphers it supports?

So far I've only been able to [find out](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) which modules are supported by my local openssl version.

When I want to read information about a [certificate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html), I can do it using:

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(sock.peer_cert)
print_status("#{ip}:#{rport} Public Key: #{cert.public_key}")
```

Is there something similar for ciphers?

Answer (score 2):

So unless there is this one request, which I still don't know - I guess this here is a pretty good description of how to enumerate the servers supported ciphers:

http://gursevkalra.blogspot.ch/2009/09/ruby-and-openssl-based-ssl-cipher.html

Answer (score -1):

You first load all the ciphers with [`openssl_add_all_ciphers`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openssl_add_all_ciphers) then you can interrogate about individual ciphers with [`EVP_get_cipherbyname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_get_cipherbyname). There are ways to enumerate the ciphers, eg. [using `OBJ_NAME_do_all_sorted`](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=107873956817083&w=2).

Ruby's OpenSSL module has a [hardcoded list](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/ext/openssl/lib/openssl/cipher.rb?view=markup):

```
 class Cipher
    %w(AES CAST5 BF DES IDEA RC2 RC4 RC5).each{|name|
      klass = Class.new(Cipher){
        define_method(:initialize){|*args|
          cipher_name = args.inject(name){|n, arg| "#{n}-#{arg}" }
          super(cipher_name)
        }
      }
```

PS. Obviously there is the [`ciphers`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ciphers) command, but that is no fun.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that this is only when you execute this when on the server? My question is geared towards scanning from outside. Just edited the question, to provide a better understandability: Will I have to enumerate the ciphers, by trying them all out, or is there a way I can request from the server which ciphers it supports?

Comment: Are you asking which ciphers does the server support (requires you to run the code on server) or which ciphers does *an SSL handshake support* ?

Comment: `sslscan --no-failed server:port` returns a list with the title _Supported Server Cipher(s)_. Basicly I want to read that information, but with ruby. Enumeration the only possibility?